# Is there a reference for what the white space character symbols represent in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, whitespace

I'm doing a text compare for a unit test in eclipse, and the difference is in whitespace, so I've got 'show white space characters' on.

[image]

Question is - is there a reference for the characters represent?

I know that the `>>` symbol is a tab ("\t"), and I imagine that pi looking symbol is probably a new line ("\n").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `U+0020` - • - Space
- `U+3000` - ˚ - Ideographic space
- `U+0009` - » - `\t` - Tab
- `U+000D` - ¤ - `\r` - Carriage return
- `U+000A` - ¶ - `\n` - Line feed

If you want to show/hide them on Eclipse

1. Go to Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors
2. Click on "configure visibility"

[image: Preferences]
[image: Configure visibility]